# Excel 3 value IF statement using date ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a conditional formatting for a range of dates.  I want anything longer than 30 days away to format green, anything within 8-30 days to be yellow and anything less than 8 days to be red.

I have tried the following formula without any luck:

```
=IF(H56<=Today()+7,"1",IF(AND(H56<Today()+30,H56>=Today()+8,"2","")))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: you are making 3 formula for the 3 conditions, right?

Comment: FYI, here's a post I wrote about [not using `IFs` in conditional formatting](http://yoursumbuddy.com/no-ifs-in-conditional-formatting-formulas/)

Comment: I am trying to create just one formula that will create 1 of 3 responses.  I am planning on making the conditional formatting based on the response (example: response 1=red, 2=yellow, 3=red, etc.)  Here is a link to the [google docs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al1tZwJOfIt2dGlBcFgwQmxPVUFRWEZEMGU3WERmaWc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Perfect!  That works exactly like I need it to.  Thank you for you help @pnuts.

Comment: @pnuts, does your formula return True or False?! it works like my first formula before editing my answer

Comment: @pnuts, in my first answer I used the same approach, but got downvotes

Answer (score 1):

OP has indicated that:

```
=IF(H56<TODAY()+8,1,IF(AND(H56<TODAY()+30,H56>TODAY()+7),2,3))
```

met his requirements.

This is a formula for use in connection with CF but not itself the formula for a CF rule. The formula would be applied to a spreadsheet in a 'normal' way - to return `1`, `2` or `3` - and then those values (only two are really necessary) applied in CF with a rule such as `Format only cells that contain` (ie not applying `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` - though that is a viable alternative where two short formulae could be applied instead of the formula above in the spreadsheet).

Comment: Good answer and explanation. Personally, it's more easier to read formula if you would use `H56-TODAY()<8` instead `H56<TODAY()+8` especially in long terms such `AND(H56<TODAY()+30,H56>TODAY()+7)` (but this is only my opinion). I'll give you upvote:)